# sql queries selection of rows based on two column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I am new to sql.I have a table as follows

```
Fruit   TotalNumber  SellAmount
Mango      5            5
Banana     4            NULL
Peach      6            6
Kiwi       7            1
Apple      9            NULL
```

I want to write a query based on the total number and sell amount.I want to retrieve all the rows where the Total number is same as sell Amount.How Can I achieve this.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a where :

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TotalNumber = SellAmount;
```

EDIT for null values :

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE TotalNumber = SellAmount
AND SellAmount IS NOT NULL;
```

If you also need TotalNumber to be superior to 0, juste add `AND SellAmount > 0`

Comment: I have few fields that has null value too

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
SELECT Fruit, TotalNumber, SellAmount 
FROM table
WHERE TotalNumber = SellAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

That was easy :-)

```
select * from MyTable where TotalNumber = SellAmount;
```